Does having proficiency in Sleight of Hand give advantage to Thieves' Tool check to pick a lock?
Thieves' Tools are the only place that picking a lock is mentioned in the PHB with a Utilize action to pick a lock. Which makes sense you'd make a Dexterity (Thieves's Tool) check.
However in the DMG in Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox under the Doors/Locked Door section it states.

Characters who don't have the key to a locked door can try to pick the lock using Thieves' Tools. The Lock Complexity table tell you how long it takes to try to pick a lock based on its complexity. At the end of that time, the character picks the lock by making a successful Dexterity (Slight of Hand) check using Thieves' Tools. The DC is determined by the lock's quality, as show in the Lock Quality table.

Tool Proficiency

If you have proficiency in a skill that's use with that check, you have Advantage on that check too.

Are you making a Dexterity (Thieves' Tools) check or a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check to pick a lock and do you get advantage from having proficiency in both Sleight of Hands and Thieves' Tools?

Related: Does proficiency with an ability check that uses a tool but not with the tool itself give any advantages for D&D 5.24?

Looking back over the rules, there advantage bonus goes both ways. Under Proficiencies it lists Tool/Equipment bonuses and profs. So I think the question which is mostly covered in the last part. Is it a Slight of Hand or Thieves' Tool check because that affects where Rogues might put their expertise. Sleight of hand is a bigger advantage because it then gives you expertise for picking pockets etc. Whereas Tools just limits to what tools are used for.

@Tashio, it's a SoH check. https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/490-lock

If you don't have proficiency in SoH it's still a DEX check and you can still add PB if you're proficient in thieves' tools.

For the record, this is a change from 5e-2014.  In 5e-2014, picking a lock would normally be a Dex ability check using only your thieves' tool proficiency.  I know some DMs allow sleight of hand proficiency as another way to add your proficiency bonus, but that's not what the 2014 PHB says.  (pg177: picking a lock is an example under "other dexterity checks", not sleight of hand or the other dex skills.)  I didn't find an existing Q&A about that for 5e-2014 to link.

Overlapping proficiencies grant advantage on the check
Tools often depend on skills. However, you can have proficiency in both the skill and the tool. So, rather than adding proficiency twice, which would be equivalent to Expertise, a character gets advantage on a skill check.

If you have proficiency with a tool, add your Proficiency Bonus to any ability check you make that uses the tool. If you have proficiency in a skill that’s used with that1 check, you have Advantage on the check too.

This was also suggested in XGTE.

Advantage. If the use of a tool and the use of a skill both apply to a check, and a character is proficient with the tool and the skill, consider allowing the character to make the check with advantage.

Picking a lock is a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check. So, if you have proficiency in both Thieves Tools and Sleight of Hand, you would add your proficiency bonus and roll at advantage.
The odds improve even further if you have Expertise in the skill, granting advantage on top of the doubled proficiency.
1: The operative "that" emphasized above almost certainly refers to the the ability check that benefits from skill proficiency--not every check.

If you have Expertise, do you roll with advantage and add your Proficiency Bonus x2, or just roll with advantage?

Added a consideration for expertise and changed the wording to avoid confusion
